# how to reshape the matrix using matlab or python

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, matrix

I have mat file including `22544384 * 63 array`. A matrix of `512*512*86`

I want to convert this array to `512*512*86*63`

How can I convert this data?

Comment: Do you want the answer in Matlab or python?    Have you tried googling how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

In Python if `'a'` is the name of the matrix, you can use:

```
from scipy.io import loatmat, savemat

data = loadmat('data.mat')
a = data['a']
a = a.reshape(512,512,86,63)
data['a'] = a
savemat('data.mat',a)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! it was created Type Error(reshape() takes from 2 to 3 positional arguments but 5 were given)